# how properly mock/test constructor with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I'd like to test Module2 constructor as well as other its functions. What is the proper way to mock Module2 constructor without breaking testFunc1, testFunc2 to test with Jest.

```
// ****************************************
// Module 1 component
class Module1 {
  init() {
    // ........
  }
}

module.exports = new Module1()


// ****************************************
// Module 2 component
const module1 = require('./module1')

class Module2 {
  constructor() {
    try {
      module1.init()
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error')
      process.exit(1)
    }
  }

  testfunc1 = () => {
    // ........
  }

  testfunc2 = () => {
    // ........
  }
}

module.exports = new Module2()
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to mock the `Module2` constructor? What test case do you have in mind, can you add the code for that?

Comment: just for test coverage... I need to test try/catch block.. e.g. if init() throws an error then catch block should be executed

Comment: So you're asking to *test* the `Module2` constructor (by mocking `module1.init` and `process.exit`), not to *mock* it?

Comment: yes. .test the constructor.. .so probably module1.init() needs to be mocked. Anyway I need to cover constructor with unittest

Comment: Yes, mock the `module1.init()` call, once with a no-op once with a throwing function, and test your constructor to behave accordingly.

Comment: so how do I mock it properly since constructor code will be executed right away once this line declared in test file: const module2 = require('./module2')

Comment: Ah, right, that's why you should not use singletons. Solutions: 1) don't use a `constructor` but an `init` method like in module1. 2) construct extra instances, either by exporting `Module2` itself as well, or by referring to `module2.constructor`. 3) mock module1, `require` module2, mock module1 differently, clear jest's module cache, `require` module2 again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing `module2`, so you need to mock `module1` rather than `module2`.

You can use [jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `module1` module. After mocking, `require` the `module2`. Besides, you should use [jest.resetModules()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules) to reset the module cache from `require.cache` object before mocking with different implementations.

E.g.

`module1.js`:

```js
class Module1 {
  init() {}
}

module.exports = new Module1();
```

`module2.js`:

```js
const module1 = require('./module1');

class Module2 {
  constructor() {
    try {
      module1.init();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error');
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }

  testfunc1 = () => {};

  testfunc2 = () => {};
}

module.exports = new Module2();
```

`module2.test.js`:

```js
describe('67099526', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('should initialize module1 correctly', () => {
    const module1instance = { init: jest.fn() };
    jest.doMock('./module1', () => {
      return module1instance;
    });
    require('./module2');
    expect(module1instance.init).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should handle error', () => {
    const exitSpy = jest.spyOn(process, 'exit').mockImplementation();
    const module1instance = {
      init: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        throw new Error('initialize module1');
      }),
    };
    jest.doMock('./module1', () => {
      return module1instance;
    });
    require('./module2');
    expect(module1instance.init).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(exitSpy).toBeCalledWith(1);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67099526/module2.test.js (11.508 s)
  67099526
    ✓ should initialize module1 correctly (8819 ms)
    ✓ should handle error (18 ms)

  console.log
    error

      at new Module2 (examples/67099526/module2.js:8:15)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |   33.33 |     100 |                   
 module2.js |     100 |      100 |   33.33 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.743 s
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. slideshowp2.. That works perfect and that's what I need. I had to try to move require() part